# for loop inside scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i multipy functions inside the scroll loop?

I have:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
b1Center = $("#block-1").offset().top - ( $(window).height() - divHeight )/2;
b1Bottom = $("#block-1").offset().top - $(window).height()
b1Top = $("#block-1").offset().top + divHeight;
if(getScrollTop() > b1Bottom && getScrollTop() < b1Top){
$("#block-1 .txt").css('marginTop', ( (getScrollTop()) *(1.6)) + 'px');
}...
```

That needs to be inside scroll function redy all the time and i have the same block for all buttons so:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dx3hr/27/

Hope this will make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divHeight = 700;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $(".blocks").each(function(){
            var this = $(this),
                Center = $(this).offset().top - ( $(window).height() - divHeight )/2,
                Bottom = $(this).offset().top - $(window).height(),
                Top = $(this).offset().top + divHeight;
            if(getScrollTop() > Bottom && getScrollTop() < Top){
                this.find('.txt').css('marginTop', ( (getScrollTop()) *(1.6)) + 'px');
            } 
        });    
    });    
});
```

Comment: As this is parallax then it wount work because the scoll will scroll all the windows at the same time and then there is no content in the window if i scroll there

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside your .scrollTop() loop:

```
$('.block').each(function  () {
    var this_block = $(this);
    this_block.whateverFunction(you, want, to, do);
});
```

Make sure to use the class of the button rather than the id...